# How can I send paginated requests to third party API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, pagination

Im building a web application in rails to fetch records from a third party API. This third party API accepts `page` parameter. For eg: `GET http://thirdpartyapi.com/records?page=2`

How can I build my html in paginated format, so that when user clicks on number 2, it should send `page=2` and when user clicks on number 4, it should send `page=4` in the requests. Is there any gem for that?

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def index
    response = HTTP.get('http://thirdparty.com/records', {query: {page: params[:page]}}) # it will return 30 items by default
    @items = response['items'].paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
end
```

This is my views

```
<%= will_paginate %>
```

Comment: https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

Comment: @Unixmonkey I think Kaminari and will_paginate do different things. In these gems, you first collect all the records and then paginate them.
My problem is , I want to show the link is my view like 1|2|3...N and when you click on any number it should send API request with `page=n`

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't provide more info. My thought was maybe you could use it's pagination links to build your interface, or fill your arrays with empty records to pad it out. Its likely simpler to build it yourself, but maybe it can help with inspiration or markup.

Comment: You should be able to use the will_paginate gem and in your controller just listen for `params[:page]` and `params[:per_page]` and pass it into your active record query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this manually it's more work than just using the [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

First you would need to get a count of records so that you know how many pages (aka how many links at the bottom you will have for pages)

```
@num_of_records = Object.count / per_page
```

Then you will need to handle that through JS depending on the number of links you want to display.

Once a user clicks on yourlink.com/?page=2 it should load with the correct data, or if you choose to you can remove elements from the div/table and insert new ones by returning them if you do an AJAX call.

Your controller would look something like this:

```
def index
    page = params[:page] || 1
    per_page = 10

    @num_of_records = Object.count / per_page

    objects_to_append = Object.paginate(:page => page, :per_page => perPage)

    render json: { success: true, objects_to_append: objects_to_append }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use kaminari instead. they have a way to do this easily. 
https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object